# Exception: null Class: class java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: arrays, blackberry, byte, concatenation, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm getting the  ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in the line shown in code below:

```java
String boundaryMessage = getBoundaryMessage(boundary, fileField, fileName, fileType);

String endBoundary = "\r\n--" + boundary + "--\r\n"; 
byte[] temp = new byte[boundaryMessage.getBytes().length+fileBytes.length+endBoundary.getBytes().length];       

temp = boundaryMessage.getBytes();
try {
    System.arraycopy(fileBytes, 0, temp, temp.length, fileBytes.length); //exception thrown here            
    System.arraycopy(endBoundary.getBytes(), 0, temp, temp.length, endBoundary.getBytes().length);
}
catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println("====Exception: "+e.getMessage()+" Class: "+e.getClass());
}
```

Can someone point me where I'm wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the fourth argument to arraycopy incorrectly, when you choose `temp.length` as the dst_position argument. This means you want to start the destination past the end of the `temp` array. The first attempt to write past the end of the array results in an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` like you are seeing.  Check the [documentation](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.1.0api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29):

```
public static void arraycopy(Object src,
                             int src_position,
                             Object dst,
                             int dst_position,
                             int length)
```

> Copies an array from the specified source array, beginning at the specified position, to the specified position of the destination array. A subsequence of array components are copied from the source array referenced by src to the destination array referenced by dst. The number of components copied is equal to the length argument. The components at positions srcOffset through srcOffset+length-1 in the source array are copied into positions dstOffset through dstOffset+length-1, respectively, of the destination array.

**Edit 22 Jan**

Your problematic line looks like this:

```
System.arraycopy(fileBytes, 0, temp, temp.length, fileBytes.length);
```

If I understand what you want to do correctly, you should be able to fix it by changing temp.length to 0, meaning that you want to copy fileBytes into the beginning of temp:

```
System.arraycopy(fileBytes, 0, temp, 0, fileBytes.length);
```

Comment: but what I really want to achieve is to copy the fileBytes array to my temp array. That's why I have done like this. I have already specified the space of the array in the begining. What more to do?